# Laser projection on the sky

Tags: safety, laser-illumination

Suppose that one points a laser beam to the sky, constantly (so that an aircraft have to deal with it).

Could that beam cause any trouble to that aircraft?

Would that individual need to obtain some sort of authorization?

Comment: Yes, pointing a laser at an aircraft poses a serious risk to those on it, please don't do it. See the link in the comment above.

Comment: @ratchetfreak that question deals with "why", this one with "if". There are instances of lasers constantly shoot at the sky, and powerful ones even: http://www.eso.org/public/images/potw1425a/

Comment: and the accepted answer addresses both (only aircraft within 12k feet will be hindered by a green 5mW laser)